# What is the Chance of Poker Flush $5/52$?

Tags: probability, card-games

> What is the Chance of Poker Flush $5/52$ ?

I think the answer should be $$\frac{C_4^1C_{13}^5}{C_{52}^5}.$$

But the writer of my textbook said
the answer is $$\frac{C_4^1C_{13}^5-C_4^1-C_4^1C_9^1}{C^5_{52}}.$$

I am confused.
Hoping someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the textbook answer wants to exclude _straight_ flushes.

Comment: I'm not sure what a "flush 5/52" is. I understand a flush to be a hand where all five cards are in the same suit, but is *not* a straight flush. Your count definitely includes the straight flushes. The $C^1_4C^1_9$ factor eliminates the straight flushes that start with Ace through $9$ by first selecting the suit and then the starting card. The $C^1_4$ factor eliminates the royal flushes by selecting the suit.

Comment: Your answer would be correct **except**: the writer is (unspoken) assuming that a straight flush is not a flush.  Other than the $(4)$ royal flushes, the straight flush can have the lowest card be anything from Ace through nine.

Comment: Thanks for all of you! The writer just said " a flush".I think Arturo Magidin has read the writer correctly : )

Comment: That is the standard definition of a "flush": e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Flush): "A flush is a hand that contains five cards all of the same suit, not all of sequential rank[.]"

Comment: Funny. In Mathematics, a continuous function is a function. In poker, a straight flush isn't a flush.

Comment: Ahha, my textbook is Chinese. I should have checked the definition. It's funny : )